# Move XML namespaces declarations to the root element

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-namespaces

I have a XML string/object:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:top xmlns:ns0="someUrl1">
<ns1:child xmlns:ns1="someUrl2">
    Value
</ns1:child>
</ns0:top>
```

How can I transform in to "normalized" namespaces XML form like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:top xmlns:ns0="someUrl1" xmlns:ns1="someUrl2">
<ns1:child>
    Value
</ns1:child>
</ns0:top>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bad idea for a few reasons (it's going to be hard to cover lots of edge cases), but (for fun and for very simple cases like the one you posed) here's an implementation using SAXParser that does this:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone extends DefaultHandler
{
    StringBuilder sb;
    private Hashtable namespaces;
    private int nsIdx;
    boolean rootDone;
    String rootNodeName;
    String rootNS;

    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        namespaces = new Hashtable();
        nsIdx = 0;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        rootDone  = false;
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        Set<String> keys = namespaces.keySet();
        StringBuilder rootEl = new StringBuilder();
        rootEl.append("<" + namespaces.get(rootNS) + ":" + rootNodeName);
            for(String key: keys){
                rootEl.append(" xmlns:" + namespaces.get(key) + "='" + key + "'");
            }
            rootEl.append(">");

            sb.insert(0, rootEl.toString());
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }    

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (!namespaces.containsKey(namespaceURI))
        {
            nsIdx++;
            namespaces.put(namespaceURI, "ns" + nsIdx);
        }
        boolean printEl = rootDone;

        if (!rootDone)
        {
            rootNodeName = localName;
            rootNS = namespaceURI;
            rootDone = true;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append("<" + namespaces.get(namespaceURI) + ":" + localName);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if (!namespaces.containsKey(atts.getURI(i)))
            {
                nsIdx++;
                namespaces.put(atts.getURI(i),"ns" + nsIdx);
            }
            if (atts.getLocalName(i) == atts.getQName(i))
            {
                sb.append(" " + atts.getLocalName(i) + "='" + atts.getValue(i) + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.append(" " + namespaces.get(atts.getURI(i)) + ":" + atts.getLocalName(i) + "='" + atts.getValue(i) + "'");
            }
        }

        if (printEl)
        {
            sb.append(">");
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        sb.append("</" + namespaces.get(uri) + ":" + localName + ">");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ns0:top xmlns:ns0=\"someUrl1\"><ns1:child xmlns:ns1=\"someUrl2\" ns0:testNS=\"tstNS\" test=\"tst\">Value</ns1:child><child2></child2><child3/></ns0:top>";
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(new Ideone());
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    }
}
```

(ideone: http://ideone.com/E4LIac)

Note that this will do the following things that may not be desireable:

- Make nodes that were self closing be empty (e.g. `<child3 />` becomes `<child3></child3>`)
- Create prefixes for unprefixed nodes (e.g. `xmlns:ns3=''`)
- Probably doesn't properly handle some other edge cases
- Probably doesn't follow the best Java conventions, I'm a bit rusty there

Also note that it just prints the final result out to `System.out` - you'd likely want to return it or save it or something else.  And I have no idea if or how this would work in groovy.

Comment: Thank you for you solution, but I was expecting to get some out of the box solution (maybe implemented in some 3d party lib)

Comment: You might do better by creating XSLT to do it and then run the XSLT through Java - but even that would be fairly complicated.  I doubt there's a third party library to do this, because it's actually a fairly complicated thing to do correctly and it may even get undone when the next consumer works on the document.